# Carpet calculator error calling a class?

Tags: java, class, object

The assignment goes as stated:

The problem
The westfield carpet company has asked you to write an application that calculates the price of carpeting for rectangular rooms. To calculate the price, you multiply the area of the floor(width times length) by the price per square foot of carpet. For example, the area of floor that is 12 feet long and 10 feet wide is 120 square feet. To cover that floor with carpet that costs $8 per square foot would cost $960 (12x10x8=960)

First, you should create a class named RoomDimension that has two Feields: one for the lenght of the room and one for the width. The RoomDimension class should have a method that returns the area of the room (the area of the room is the room's length multiplied by the room's width).

Next, you should create a RoomCarpet class that has a RoomDimension object as a field. It should also have a field for the cost of the carpet per square foot. The RoomCarpet class should have a method that returns the total cost of the carpet.

Once you have written these classes, use them in an application that asks the user to enter the dimensions of a room and the price per square foot of the desired carpeting. The application should display the total cost of the carpet.

The code I have below can't seem to run due to an error in the 31st line of the MainProgram

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MainProgram {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final double CARPET_PRICE_PER_SQFT = 8.0;

        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Display intro.
        System.out.println("This program will display the "
                + "carpet cost of a room." + "\nPlease enter the room's "
                + "dimension in feet.");

        // Get the length of the room.
        System.out.print("Enter the length of room: ");
        double length = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Get the width of the room.
        System.out.print("Enter the width of room: ");
        double width = keyboard.nextDouble();

        //close keyboard
        keyboard.close();

        ****// Create RoomDimension and RoomCarpet objects.
        CarpetCalculatorProgram calculatorProgram = new CarpetCalculatorProgram();
        RoomDimension dimensions = calculatorProgram.new RoomDimension(length,
                width);
        RoomCarpet roomCarpet = calculatorProgram.new RoomCarpet(dimensions,
                CARPET_PRICE_PER_SQFT);****

        // Print the object calling the toString
        System.out.println(roomCarpet);
    }
}
```

Here are the other classes for the code:

Room Dimension

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RoomDimension {

    private double length;
    private double width;

    public RoomDimension(double length, double width) {
        super();
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return length * width;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RoomDimension [length=" + length + ", width=" + width + "]";
    }


}
```

Room Carpet

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RoomCarpet {

      private RoomDimension roomDimensions;
        private double costOfCarpet;

        public RoomCarpet(RoomDimension roomDimensions, double costOfCarpet) {
            super();
            this.roomDimensions = roomDimensions;
            this.costOfCarpet = costOfCarpet;
        }

        public double getTotalCost() {
            return costOfCarpet * roomDimensions.getArea();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "RoomCarpet [roomDimensions=" + roomDimensions
                    + ", costOfCarpet=" + costOfCarpet + ", "
                            + "total cost=" + getTotalCost() + "]";
        }

}
```

Comment: `due to an error`: is this a secret error? If not, then add it to the question. And what is line `31` in `MainProgram`?

Comment: What error? Which is line 31?

Comment: My apologies, the code specifically:  // Create RoomDimension and RoomCarpet objects.
        CarpetCalculatorProgram calculatorProgram = new CarpetCalculatorProgram();
        RoomDimension dimensions = calculatorProgram.new RoomDimension(length,
                width);
        RoomCarpet roomCarpet = calculatorProgram.new RoomCarpet(dimensions,
                CARPET_PRICE_PER_SQFT);

Comment: Well, this looks like sourcecode and not like an exception message ...

Comment: @KennyBowen **Post your stack trace.** See also http://sscce.org/ and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If you want free help don't make us pull teeth.

Comment: I don't think `RoomDimension dimensions = calculatorProgram.new RoomDimension(length, width);` is a correct syntax! Remove `calculatorProgram.` from there. Edit: actually, I don't see the need of `calculatorProgram` at all...

Comment: The thing is @AndrewT. without that, the System.out.println(Roomcarpet); is not being called and therefore not being displayed..

Comment: NO NO. Your doing that for hacking out some other error it looks like. Is `RoomDimension` an inner class of calculatorProgram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error I get when I paste all the things into my IDE is

> CarpetCalculatorProgram cannot be resolved to a type

Assuming that there are no classes you didn't post:

There is no `CarpetCalculatorProgram` class and there are no inner `RoomDimension` / `RoomCarpet` classes in there. `RoomDimension` is actually an independent top level class. The code must either be

```
    // Create RoomDimension and RoomCarpet objects.
    RoomDimension dimensions = new RoomDimension(length,
            width);
    RoomCarpet roomCarpet = new RoomCarpet(dimensions,
            CARPET_PRICE_PER_SQFT);
```

instead of using `new EnclosingClass().new InnerClass()` syntax. OR

```
    // Create RoomDimension and RoomCarpet objects.
    CarpetCalculatorProgram calculatorProgram = new CarpetCalculatorProgram();
    CarpetCalculatorProgram.RoomDimension dimensions = calculatorProgram.new RoomDimension(length,
            width);
    CarpetCalculatorProgram.RoomCarpet roomCarpet = calculatorProgram.new RoomCarpet(dimensions,
            CARPET_PRICE_PER_SQFT);
```

AND the two classes moved into the CarpetCalculatorProgram class:

```
public class CarpetCalculatorProgram {
    public class RoomDimension {
        ...
    }

    public class RoomCarpet {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Well my code is working properly, see if it helps you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class RoomDimension{
        private int length;
        private int width;

    public RoomDimension(int length, int width){
            this.length= length;
            this.width= width;
    }
    public int Area(){
        int area= this.length* this.width;
        return area;
    }
    public int getlength(){
        return this.length;
    }
    public int getwidth(){
        return width;
    }
    }

    class RoomCarpet{
        private RoomDimension RD;
        private int costperSq;

    public RoomCarpet(RoomDimension RD, int costperSq){
        this.RD= RD;
        this.costperSq= costperSq;
    }

    public int TotalCost(){
        return this.costperSq* RD.Area();
    }
}
```

[Main]

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter the length the room");
        int L= sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("enter the width the room");
        int W= sc.nextInt();

        RoomDimension RD= new RoomDimension(L, W);

        System.out.println("enter how much the carpet costs per sq");
        int cost= sc.nextInt();

        RoomCarpet RC= new RoomCarpet(RD, cost);

        System.out.println("total cost of the carpet will be= "+RC.TotalCost());
    }
}
```

Comment: Add description of what you think went wrong and why your code fixes it.